# How to build Regular Expression for more strict Anchor tag

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to restrict some of the attributes that can go with anchor tag in HTML for Markdown editor. This is what I have right now:

```
/^(<a\shref="((https?|ftp):\/\/|\/)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+"(\stitle="[^"<>]+")?\s?>|<\/a>)$/i
```

This allows an anchor tag with `title` and `href` attributes but nothing else. I also wanted to add `target` but whatever I tried didn't work.

1. The link must contain an `href` attribute.
2. It can contain `title` attribute but doens't have to.
3. It can contain `target` attribute but doesn't have to too.

How can I modify the Regex above which satisfies all the conditions above.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: What about `title = "xyz"` (i.e. spaces around `=`)? What if the attributes appear in another order?

Comment: As far as I see you already have #1 and #2 covered. Just clode `title` rule to `target` one. Also, a bit strange ending `|<\/a>)$`? You sure you did not meant `.*?<\/a>)$`? (`.*?` instead of `|`)

Comment: <a\s+ a plus sign is needed here

Comment: You should not be parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually regexes aren't the best tool for parsing some languages. On the other hand, if you just want to match an isolated anchor tag, then a parser could be a little too much, and regexes can do a decent job.

To **match an anchor tag to your requirements**, you can use the regex below. It uses backreferencing to keep track of **at most** one `title` and one `target` (duplicated attributes), also at least/most one `href`:

```
^(<a(?=[^>]*?(\s+href="((https?|ftp):\/\/|\/)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+")[^>]*>)(?=([^>]*?(\s+title="[^"<>]+"))?[^>]*>)(?=([^>]*?(\s+target="[^"<>]+"))?[^>]*>)(\2(\6\8?)?|\2\8\6?|\6\2\8?|\8\2\6?|\6\8\2|\8\6\2)\s*>[^<]*</a>)$
```

Check the [demo here](http://regexr.com?36090), along with dozens of test cases which you can proof test the solution.

Observe this regex is not so complicated (the "ugly" part is the URL, really), but it is very comprehensive and takes care of:

- a mandatory `href` attribute
- an optional `title` attribute
- an optional `target` attribute
- no other type of attribute is allowed (altought it would be easy to customize and add support)
- any number of spaces between them
- they can come in **any order**
- there can be at most one `href`, one `title` and one `target`.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have tested it? It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: How would you make the order of the attributes flexible?

Comment: Ok, updated the answer, reworked the regex a bit. Check the example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: Hey, I added another regex, a slightly more complicated version of the last one. The "bonus" is that it takes care of duplicated attributes. Check the demo for some examples. Also, if you want, I can put an explanation for them. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx-en **by themselves** aren't really good at this kind of thing.

I'd do something like:

```
function validateAnchor(anchor){

    var match,
        name,
        value,
        test,
        attrRE=/\s([a-z]+)(?:\s*=\s*"([^"]+))?"/gi, // matches one tag attribute
        allowedAttrs={ // attributes must appear here to be considered legal
          href:{
            isValid:function(val){
               return isValidURL(val);
            }
          },
          title:{
            isValid:function(val){
                return true;
            }
          },
          target:{
            isValid:function(val){
              return true;
            }
          }
        },
        result=true;

    while(match=attrRE.exec(anchor)){

        name=match[1].toLowerCase(); // lowerCase to match our allowedAttrs keys
        value=match[2]||'';          // optional

        // must have a name
        if(!name){
            console.log('no name for this attr - should not happen!');
            result=false;
            break;
        }

        // and must exist in allowedAttrs
        if(test=allowedAttrs[name]) {
            console.log('unknown attr');
            result=false;
            break;
        }

        // if it has a value and there is am isValid function.
        if(value && 'function'==typeof(attr.isValid)){
            if(!attr.isValid(value)){ // which fails!
                result=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, that given:

```
var anchor='<a href=\"...\" target = \"...\" foo >';
```

validateAnchor(anchor) will fail since 'foo' is a disallowed attribute (not defined in allowedAttrs).

The benefits of this approach are that you

- don't need to modify your RE each time you need to accept a new attribute,
- can have value-less attributes

I leave isValidURL() for you to define.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it easier:

```
/<a(?=.*href="((ht|f)tps?:\/)?\/.*")\s*((href|title|target)="[^"]*"\s*)*>[^<]*</a>/
```